# How to save data in database using HABTM in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have included

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end  

class Subjects < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have created one table i.e subjects_users having subject_id and user_id

```
<% Subject.all.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Select Subject', final_subject_subject_path(subject)  %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

It goes in controller method:

```
def final_subject
    # now please guide me what I have to write in this so that when select subject is clicked than it will both current_user.id and subject.id in associated table
  end
```

Please help me out in solving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create subjects for a particular user, you can do it as:

```
def final_subject
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id)
    current_user.subjects << @subject
end
```

Comment: No I dont want to create subject I just want when student will cllick on subject than it will go to final_subject method and just create on row in table subjects_users with subjectid and user_id